# Custom Desktop with dconf

Tags: 20.04, dconf

I would like to be able to lock my desktop down or customize it.

I have read that I could do this with `dconf`, but I can't seem to get this to work on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have installed a vanilla Ubuntu desktop and made the following config:

```
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks

vi /etc/dconf/profile/user
user-db:user
system-db:local

vi /etc/dconf/profile/user
user-db:user
system-db:local


vi /etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-lockdown
[org/gnome/desktop/lockdown]
disable-log-out='true'


vi /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/lockdown
/org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/disable-log-out


dconf update

reboot
```

But this does not seem to effect the user at all. If I use `dconf-editor`, I can make something work, but I would like to be able do this via `puppet`.

Comment: Basically you want to lock the key disable-logout n your DE is vanilla GNOME rite??

Comment: Yeah first set the key to true so the user cant lock out and then lock the key so the user cant change it

Comment: thank you very mutch :)

Comment: i just installed ubuntu-desktop.....then it auto installed gdm3 along with it

Comment: apt install ubuntu-desktop is all i did

Answer (score 1):

i have found the error in my setup......in the /etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-lockdown i have set the key ....but i have made it with a string and not a boolean......if i change the key to disable-log-out=true insted of disable-log-out='true' ..it works

Comment: Oh ok.. Thats fine.. I did all my trails without thise quotes and thats why it worked since morning.. And yes I am wrong about setting the key via cli.. I learnt a lesson..

Comment: Many thx for another set of eyes :)